# PWM ~100mA LED's

Tags: led, pwm

If someone knows of a prototyping solution for driving several LED's at >75mA I'd be grateful.

I've taken 8 LED's out of an existing product. They appear to expect 70mA to 100mA for max brightness. I've looked around for breakout board solutions to dimming or driving these LED's but most breakout boards for multiple channels that I can find either have a max of around <200mA for all channels together or around 35mA max per channel. I have yet to find something with a [LT3760](http://www.linear.com/product/LT3760) (for example).

Comment: Are you asking for a circuit, or a ready-made device to drive the LEDs?

Comment: I'm looking for a ready-made, PCB

Comment: Then this is off topic. Closing.

Comment: Excluse me, can you point to where in the guidelines asking about PCB's is off topic? You're version of electrical engineering might not be everyones

Comment: We don't do shopping questions here.

Comment: You'd be hardpressed to build any eletronics without some shopping. Again, reference please. What I could find says "Is your question about electronics design?" and I think this qualifies

Comment: It's not my job to read the site rules to you.  Shopping questions are off topic.

Comment: Asking for a reference/link to where I can better understand the logic behind killing a question is pretty fare. Calling this a "shopping" question isn't clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use several mosfets.One for each led circuit .     Here is an example of one circuit for one led: [MOSFET LED CIRCUIT](http://www.pcbheaven.com/userpages/LED_driving_and_controlling_methods/?topic=worklog&p=3)

Comment: based on the feedback I feel this is the route I have to go. Many thanks. If it's okay with you I'll dig into the resource you posted and then close the question later after I've understood it.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is of course the [LT3760 demo board](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/DC1573A/DC1573A-ND/4866565). Available at Digikey or Linear.

Its not cheap though. If you are doing this LED-thingie for a product that will be sold, Linear might give you a demo board for free.

Comment: It's not going to be sold. It's for an art project (of course) and ill be stuffing the LED's back into another device. Because of the "stuffing" the demo board is a bit large. But I suppose if I had the time I could use this as a reference design and build my own. I was kinda looking for something more like https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10616 but I realize I'm slicing hairs and you are right... with half decent and reasonable effor the demo board would be fine